# Conditionally Output Variables through Custom PHP Function

Tags: php, function, wrapper

I wrote a really simple function thinking it would only output its parameter if it exists:

```
  function hurl($var,$default="")
  {
    if(isset($var) && !is_null($var) && gettype($var) != "object" && gettype($var) != "array")
        return $var;
    return $default;
  }
```

This way you can simply hurl($_POST['variable']) and it wouldn't generate an error if the POST variable didn't exist. But I still get an error as if it is trying to reference a value that doesn't exist.

Then i read a notice on the [isset() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

> Note: Because this is a language construct and not a function, it
>   cannot be called using variable functions.

This linked me to [Variable Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) which read:

> Variable functions won't work with language constructs such as echo,
>   print, unset(), isset(), empty(), include, require and the like.
>   Utilize [wrapper functions](http://php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php) to make use of any of these constructs as
>   variable functions.

How can I do this? Could someone write an example, or a simpler method of checking without having to constantly write isset() and is_null() all over the page? Would a try catch statement work in this scenario somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function hurl($key, $value='') {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $_POST)) {
        if (!is_object($_POST[$key]) && !is_array($_POST[$key])) {
            $value = $_POST[$key];
        }
    }
    return $value
}
```

Comment: Thought of this solution too, but didn't know if RecoJohnson wanted a solution for all kind of variables.